# get many urls at a time in android using json

Tags: android, json

In this I use only one URl http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=1;

Instead of this, I want to use more URL at a time ,for example

1. http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=1
2. http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=2

Here I am using List View, when I click id =1 it must redirect to corresponding url http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=1 and so forth

```
protected J SON Object do In Background(String... strings) {
    String response=GetString.getJSONfromURL("http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=1");

    try{
        return new J SON Object(response);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.print Stack Trace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Had you heard about loops?

Comment: yes ...but I don't Know how to use Here,can u please help me

Comment: how to fetch data from unique Id’s...I mean if enter id=, or id = 2 or id=3 and so on then display the following details..how to set?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's JSONObject (not J SON Object), doInBackground (not do In Background), printStackTrace() (not print Stack Trace), etc..

As suggested, a loop will do it, something along those lines

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    String response = 
getString.getJSONfromURL("http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=" + (i+1));
    try { 
       //the rest of your code...
 }
```

But honestly it seems like you should review a little bit more how java works before trying to write android apps. ;)